# Errors adding users to Mongodb on Ubuntu linux

Tags: authentication, mongodb

I am trying to add admin users to a Mongodb running on Ubuntu Linux on AWS -
working from the mongo shell, I first 'use admin', then when I run db.addUser("admin', "password) 
the command fails saying  "Can't take a write lock while out of disk space",

I checked disk space and there is 1GB remaining - any help?

Comment: "Can't take a write lock while out of disk space" - obviously you are running out of diskspace - either on the filesystem with the database files or TMPDIR...provide evidence if you disagree with this point.

Comment: It is unusual for MongoDB to have to create a new extent when adding a user, but it can happen. You will need to check that the volume with MongoDB data in it has enough space, and that the volume for tmp has enough space.  Also, while it doesn't help with this specific issue, 1GB is really not enough free space to run a server that is doing any real work.

Comment: I started a 16 GB instance, and the problems went away - I also modified mongodb.conf and set auth=true and then just rebooted the server - thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I have been working with EC2 instances for some years and I found similar errors using software that does not have nothing in common with MongoDB, so I bet that it's a problem related with EC2 disk volumes management rather than a MongoDB issue.

In my opinion it should be one of the following errors:

- You have started MongoDB with a user that cannot modify the Mongo data directory. Are you sure that you have started up MongoDB using a user with write permissions on the data directory?
- The MongoDB data directory points to a full disk volume (it is something usual when software is installed using apt, yum or whatever package manager on Amazon EC2 instances). Check your MongoDB data directory configuration and use 'df -h' on the command line to see how much available disk space you have.

Comment: Thanks for your replies - I use the default /data/db, and chown ownership on that directory to ubuntu , the user that launches mongodb I will increase my volume to 12 GB and see if that solves it